# SQL delete all rows with date older than x days

Tags: database, sqlite

I have a table like below and I am trying delete all rows with createdDate older than 10 days form current date, like last 3 streams to be deleted form table

```
ID  Name    createdDate(string)
76  Stream1 2018-10-18T00:00:00 
70  Stream2 2018-10-17T00:00:00 
50  Stream3 2018-10-03T00:00:00 
32  Stream4 2018-09-22T00:00:00 
21  Stream5 2018-09-21T00:00:00
```

I tried below queried but didn't work, can some one help

```
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE TO_DATE(createdDate) < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY))

DELETE FROM myTable WHERE TO_DATE(createdDate) < NOW()- INTERVAL 10 DAY;
```

Comment: There is no `to_date()` function in MySQL! Are you using Orace database instead ?

Comment: I would avoid wrapping the column in a function in the where clause, and reference the bare column instead. If the column is in a canonical format where we can use `<` and `>` comparisons to work like datetime comparisons. Note that MySQL has specific datatypes DATE and  DATETIME which are custom implemented to handle date and datetime values.)

Answer (score 1):

For performance, to allow MySQL to use a range scan (using an index with `createdDate` as the leading column), I would reference the *bare* column in the `WHERE` clause.

I would do any required manipulation on the literal side of the comparison, to come up with a string that we can compare the bare column to.

I'd write a SELECT statement first, to verify that it's working (before we run a DELETE and find out that it deletes more than we expected)

We can test expressions in a simple SELECT statement, e.g.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( NOW() + INTERVAL -10 DAY , '%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00') AS dt
```

Then we can use that expression in a WHERE clause

```
SELECT t.* 
  FROM myTable t 
WHERE t.createddate  <   DATE_FORMAT( NOW() + INTERVAL -10 DAY , '%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00')
ORDER BY t.createddate DESC
```

This expression is using midnight `'00:00:00'` as the time component; there are other expressions that would achieve an equivalent result.

```
WHERE t.createddate  <   DATE_FORMAT( DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -10 DAY , '%Y-%m-%dT%T')
```

We really need to narrow down and be specific what is meant by "older than 10 days than current date".

Once we are sure that the query is returning the rows we want to delete, I would convert this into a DELETE statement by replacing the SELECT keyword, and omitting the ORDER BY

```
SELECT t.* 
  FROM myTable t 
WHERE t.createddate  <   DATE_FORMAT( NOW() + INTERVAL -10 DAY , '%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00')
```

Comment: OP is not even using MySQL. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52879090/sql-delete-all-rows-with-date-older-than-x-days/52879168?noredirect=1#comment92674515_52879168

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya: my mistake. I the question is tagged MySQL.  No mention in the question that OP is using SQLite.

Comment: Not your mistake. Question was tagged MySQL. Everybody did the solution assuming MySQL. Anyways +1 for the performance part. Something noteworthy for me

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `to_date()` is a function in MySQL.  Just use `date()`:

```
DELETE FROM myTable
WHERE DATE(createdDate) < NOW() - INTERVAL 10 DAY;
```

Comment: TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,  CURDATE() ), createdDate) >= 10

Answer (score 0):

There is no `To_date()` function in MySQL. You will need to use [`Str_To_Date()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function instead:

### [DB Fiddle DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eWuWiivrk3VmFehVK5kQMD/1)

```
DELETE FROM myTable 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(createdDate, '%Y-%m-%dT%T') < NOW()- INTERVAL 10 DAY;
```

**Details:**

- `%Y`     Year as a numeric, 4-digit value
- `%m`     Month name as a numeric value (00 to 12)
- `%d`     Day of the month as a numeric value (01 to 31)
- `%T`     Time in 24 hour format (hh:mm:ss)
- There is an additional 'T' substring in your datetime string. That is represented directly by using `T`

Comment: I am getting this error :::::::::: getting below error ::: near "10": syntax error: DELETE FROM myTable WHERE DATE(createdDate) < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10

Comment: @jayesh you are trying someone else's code. Please check my code. I am not using date function, but str_to_date()

Comment: i am getting that issue for this too::::::::::: near "10": syntax error: DELETE FROM myTable WHERE STR_TO_DATE(createdDate, '%Y-%m-%dT%T') < NOW()- INTERVAL 10

Comment: @jayesh check db fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eWuWiivrk3VmFehVK5kQMD/1 

It is working perfectly fine. Are you sure that you are using MySQL ?

Comment: I am  using this query in SQLite , mobile local storage database

Comment: @jayesh Why did you tag MySQL ? Dont you understand that there is a big difference between MySQL and SQLite ?

Comment: my bad,That was a mistake, I modified the question

Answer (score 0):

i think date conversion need in both side of comparison

```
   DELETE FROM myTable 
   WHERE DATE(createdDate) < date(NOW()- INTERVAL 10 DAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no function `TO_DATE` in MySQL. You can try this query instead:

```
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE DATE(createDate) < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY);
```

Comment: getting below error :::           near "10": syntax error: DELETE FROM myTable WHERE DATE(createdDate) < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10

Answer (score -1):

DELETE FROM myTable t WHERE t.createdDate< NOW() - INTERVAL 10 DAY;

Comment: What is the difference to Gordon Linoff's answer which was posted 3 years ago?